# component not re-rendering after redux state change

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a navigation component and its colors depend on a redux state hash.

I have this navigation component inside another component in which I am trying to implement an effect where the colors of the link and its state change depending on the content I click on.

Everything is connected and I can see the state change in redux-logger but the navigation component does not re-render. However, when I hover over the link, it reflects the changes.

the redux state looks like this

```
  navProperties: {
    bold: "black",
    dim: "gray",
    social: "#724474",
    socialText: "white",
    socialHover: "#dbb7c8"
  }
```

when the parent component and navbar are rendered for the first time, the changeNavProperties(propertiesHash) works and the colors reflect what I set in componentWillMount();

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.selectNavLink(this.props.match.url);
    this.props.changeNavProperties({
      bold: "black",
      dim: "gray",
      social: "#4d6cb7",
      socialText: "white",
      socialHover: "#738dce"
    });
  }
```

Here's my action and reducer

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_NAV_PROPERTIES":
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

```
export function changeNavProperties(newProperties) {
  return {
    type: "CHANGE_NAV_PROPERTIES",
    payload: newProperties
  };
}
```

this is the function I am calling in the parent component. Click on an li changes the color of one of the Navbar items

```
class Skills extends Component {

  ...

  handleClick = e => {
    if (e.target.innerHTML === "HTML") {
      this.props.changeNavProperties({
        bold: "white",
        dim: "#333333",
        social: "#e44d26",
        socialText: "white",
        socialHover: "#738dce"
      });
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="skills-container">
        <Navbar />
        <ul>
            <li onClick={this.handleClick}>HTML</li>

        ...

      </div>
    );
  }
}
  ...

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      selectedNavLink: state.selectedNavLink
    };
  }

  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ selectNavLink, changeNavProperties }, 
  dispatch);
  }

  export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(Skills);
```

Navbar component

```
class Navbar extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setNavProperties();
  }

  setNavProperties = () => {
    document.querySelector(
      ".logo h1"
    ).style.color = this.props.navProperties.bold;
    document.querySelector(
      ".navigation hr"
    ).style.borderColor = this.props.navProperties.bold;
    let navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".navigation a");

    navLinks.forEach(link => {
      link.style.color = this.props.navProperties.dim;
      if (link.getAttribute("href") === this.props.selectedNavLink) {
        link.parentElement.classList.remove("inactive-link");
        link.parentElement.classList.add("active-link");
        link.style.color = this.props.navProperties.bold;
      }
    });

    let socialMedia = document.querySelectorAll(".social-media i");
    socialMedia.forEach(icon => {
      icon.style.background = this.props.navProperties.social;
      icon.style.color = this.props.navProperties.socialText;
    });
  };


  ...


  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      selectedNavLink: state.selectedNavLink,
      navProperties: state.navProperties
    }; 
  }

  function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ selectNavLink }, dispatch);
  }

  export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(Navbar);
}
```

Comment: please give more information about your container

Comment: Please show how you are connecting your component to the store via connect and mapStateToProps()

Comment: you need to update the state in redux but you are not doing instead you are just returning payload as you receive

Comment: @JasperBernales I updated the code

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I updated the code

Comment: @KannanG I thought the payload becomes the new redux state? I am passing a new hash with different key-value pairs.

Comment: no, it wont. you need to update the state so that react can recognize there was a change happened. and allow UI to re-draw the UI

Comment: did you connect the Navbar to redux?

Comment: @KannanG I added it like you said and nothing has changed.                   export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_NAV_PROPERTIES:
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

Comment: @JasperBernales Yeah, both components are connected to the redux state tree

Comment: I can't see in your store the `selectedNavLink`.

Comment: please post the navbar connect

Comment: @JosephD. It's in the store, but that's not crucial in this case. I am clicking on the <li>

Comment: @JasperBernales i just updated it

Comment: have you try like this? return Object.assign({}, state, {
        selectedNavLink: action.payload
      });

Answer (score 1):

you need to update the state in redux but you are not doing instead you are just returning payload as you receive

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_NAV_PROPERTIES":
      /*update the state so that you can re-render data in UI*/
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        selectedNavLink: action.payload
      }); /*do it like the above*/
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Read the below for more detail - https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers

Answer (score 0):

Your payload contains the nav properties when you dispatch `"CHANGE_NAV_PROPERTIES"` action.

The lacking part is to make sure to assign it correctly to `navProperties`.

```
case "CHANGE_NAV_PROPERTIES":
  return {
    ...state,
    navProperties: action.payload // assign it to navProperties key in store
  };
```

or using `Object.assign()`:

```
case "CHANGE_NAV_PROPERTIES":
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    navProperties: action.payload
  });
```

Comment: export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_NAV_PROPERTIES:
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

Comment: no matter what I do, it's the same. i see the redux state change but the component does not immediately reflect the changes

Comment: `"no matter what I do, it's the same."` - the snippet you commented is different. it's never assigning to `navProperties`.

Comment: @toekneeyou, see two options carefully. what's the error by the way?

Comment: Sorry, no errors lol. It updates the tree like everybody else's methods but component does not immediately reflect changes until I hover over a link

Comment: also, the object.assign method inserts a key-value pair navProperties: action.payload into the previous state

Answer (score 0):

This

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_NAV_PROPERTIES":
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Should be like this:

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_NAV_PROPERTIES":
      return { ...state, navProperties: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The reason for the above change provided is your method is overriding everything in the redux store. Simply put you're mutating the store by returning `action.payload`.

Forgive any typo, I wrote this answer using my phone.

Comment: why should it be like that?

Comment: Hi, same problem, everybody's method updates the redux tree, but component does not rerender immediately. When I hover over the nav links, then they change

Comment: In that case kindly reproduce this issue using codesandbox or stackblitz